# Center a widget in a layout with Qt Designer

Tags: qt, layout, qt-designer

Consider a dialog window:

[image]

I want button 1 to be centered horizontally, and button 2 to be in the right corner. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can put a horizontal layout that contains a horizontal spacer, pushbutton and another horizontal layout. This second horizontal layout contains a horizontal spacer and a pushbutton.

Something like this:

[image]